# Receiving the error "failed to compute cache key: "/sh" not found: not found" when running Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile, apache-nifi

### I downloaded the Dockerfile script used for creating an Apache NiFi image, when building the image I receive the following error:
=> ERROR [2/8] ADD sh/ /opt/nifi/scripts/                                                                                                                                                                                                      0.0s

> [2/8] ADD sh/ /opt/nifi/scripts/:

---

failed to compute cache key: "/sh" not found: not found

Not sure why this error is coming, I am executing the docker file which is present in current directory so the path should not be an issue. Please help

The NiFI docker script can be obtained here: https://hub.docker.com/r/apache/nifi/dockerfile

The part of the script that is causing the issues is as follows:

```
ARG IMAGE_NAME=openjdk
ARG IMAGE_TAG=8-jre
FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
ARG MAINTAINER="Apache NiFi <dev@nifi.apache.org>"
LABEL maintainer="${MAINTAINER}"
LABEL site="https://nifi.apache.org"

ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=1000
ARG NIFI_VERSION=1.19.0
ARG BASE_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist
ARG MIRROR_BASE_URL=${MIRROR_BASE_URL:-${BASE_URL}}
ARG DISTRO_PATH=${DISTRO_PATH:-${NIFI_VERSION}}
ARG NIFI_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_BINARY_PATH:-     /nifi/${DISTRO_PATH}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}
ARG NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH:-   /nifi/${DISTRO_PATH}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}

ENV NIFI_BASE_DIR=/adityavenkat/opt/nifi
ENV NIFI_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-current
ENV NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-current

ENV NIFI_PID_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/run
ENV NIFI_LOG_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/logs

ADD sh/ ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/
RUN chmod -R +x ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/*.sh
```

Comment: That error message translates to "there is no directory `./sh/` relative to the directory you passed as the `docker build` argument".  Does that directory exist on the host?  Can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: I check and was not able to find a ./sh/ folder anywhere, I will try creating one and see if it works